# Debugging idle postgres query executed from sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a batch query that I'm running daily on my database. However, it seems to get stuck in idle state, and I'm having a lot of difficulty debugging what's going on.

The query is an aggregation on a table that is simultaneously getting inserted, which I'm guessing somehow relates to the issue. (The aggregation is on the previous days data, so the insertions shouldn't affect results.)

Clues

1. I'm running this inside a python script using sqlalchemy. However, I've set transaction level to autocommit, so I don't think things are getting wrapped inside a transaction. On the other hand, I don't see the query hang when I run it manually in sql terminal.
2. By querying `pg_stat_activity`, the query initially comes into the database as state='active'. After maybe 15 seconds, the state changes to 'idle' and additionally, the xact_start is set to NULL. The waiting flag is never set to true.
3. Before I figured out the transaction level autocommit for sqlalchemy, it would instead hang in state 'idle in transaction' rather than 'idle'. And it possibly hangs slightly less frequently since making that change?

I feel like I'm not equipped to dig any deeper than I have on this. Any feedback, even explaining more about different states and relevant postgres internals without giving a definite answer, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know what exactly query is running? Can you just call it by yourself to database? Are you sure that problem on python side?

Comment: I know the exact query and can successfully call from command line. Based on that, I'm inclined to think it's a python problem. But I haven't found the root problem yet.

Comment: I don't know what you used for debug, so can you run script with debugger step by step and find where query becomes idle? This is how to use pdb: `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`. `n` - next step, `s` - step into, `help` - for help.

Comment: pdb doesn't work - it hangs in the engine.execute.

Comment: did you solve this? I am also getting a hang in engine.execute. Everything was working fine an hour ago and now, it freezes.

Comment: I switched over to the raw psycopg2 cursor and did `cursor.autocommit = True` (I think that is the API.) There are some timeout settings that you can fiddle with in sqlalchemy connection pools that might fix things, but it was easier for me just to deal with the raw cursor.